# Creating my own arrayName.push() function

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a code that puts the highest score into a new array and i don't want to use the push function. Please take a look at my code, i really dont know what to put in bestSolutions[?] as i would like it to be a new array containing the index of the highestScores.

```
var scores = [60,50,60,58,54,54,58,50,52,54,48,69,34,55,51,52,44,51,69,64,66,55,52,61,46,31,57,52,44,18,41,53,55,61,51,44];
var bestSolutions = [];
var highScore = 0;
var j = 0
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    if (scores[i] > highScore){
        highScore = scores[i];
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    if (scores[i] == highScore){
        bestSolutions[] = i
    }

}
console.log(bestSolutions)
console.log(highScore);
```

Comment: "*... i don't want to use the push function.*" A bit tangential to your question, but any reason why?

Comment: Also, why are you using an Array to store what will be a single value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

```
bestSolutions.unshift(i);
```

You could alternatively just explicitly set the index:

```
bestSolutions[0] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scores = [60,50,60,58,54,54,58,50,52,54,48,69,34,55,51,52,44,51,69,64,66,55,52,61,46,31,57,52,44,18,41,53,55,61,51,44];
var bestSolutions = [];
var highScore = 0;
var j = 0
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    if (scores[i] > highScore){
        highScore = scores[i];
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    if (scores[i] == highScore){
        bestSolutions[bestSolutions.length] = i //Here the change
    }

}
console.log(bestSolutions)
console.log(highScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the last index + 1, which is fortunately the arrays length:

```
 bestSolutions[bestSolutions.length] = i;
```

Given that `.push` does exactly that, I don't see a reason why you want to avoid it.